# Flash not shown with i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, pundit

My flash message doesn't show when I use i18n, but does when I just use a string. This is in the application controller.

This works:

```
def user_not_authorized(exception)
    policy_name = exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore
    ## require 'pry'; binding.pry
flash[:alert] = "You're not invited for this event."
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_path
end
```

This doesn't show anything:

```
def user_not_authorized(exception)
    policy_name = exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore
    ## require 'pry'; binding.pry
    flash[:error] = I18n.t "#{policy_name}.#{exception.query}", scope: 'pundit',
                       default: [:default, "I'm sorry, you're not allowed"]
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_path
end
```

I tried using just `t` instead of `I18n.t` but no effect either.

When using `pry` and running the `I18n.t` it shows the expected String.

**The i18n file:**

```
pundit:
  default: "I'm sorry, but you're not allowed to see this."
  event_policy:
    show?: 'You cannot view this event. You need an invitation first.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have `flash[:alert]` on the first code and `flash[:error]` on the second one, does using `:alert` fixes your issue?

Comment: @arieljuod wow. 2hours in, and this is the fix!

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about the Flash hash, you can use :error if you want, just be sure to update the part of your layout that renders that https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Comment: Thanks. I've been Ruby'ing for a short while now. Lots of manual parts to read!